# How many CPUs should be allocated to an Elasticsearch node that doesn't store data?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch recommends using multi-core processors for Elasticsearch nodes according to their docs but doesn't recommend the number of CPU cores required for peak performance of indexing and searches. Based on the answer to the [question on maxing out CPUs in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611302/how-to-max-out-cpu-cores-on-elasticsearch-cluster) during a search on elasticsearch, each shard of an index would utilize one CPU thread during searches.

If I were to deploy Elasticsearch with the following architecture:

- 3 Master only nodes

  `node.master: true
  node.data:false`
- 3 Search load-balancer nodes

  `node.master: false
  node.data:false`
- 3 or more Data nodes with `number_of_replicas = 2` and `number_of_shards = 8` for each index hosted on these nodes

  `node.master: false
  node.data:true`

then,

1. Does the Search Load-balancer nodes need 1 CPU per shard like the Data nodes to process the searches on the indexes or can it process the searches efficiently with a lower CPU count of 2 or 4?
2. Does the Master nodes need 1 CPU per shard to process the ingest traffic or would this be an inefficient design?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Master Load-balancer"? Can you expand on this?

Comment: I believe those are tie breaker nodes?

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant Master nodes (i.e. node.master:true; node.data:false). I've updated the question